# wordpress child theme twentyeleven showing featured images

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress-featured-image

I am trying to make a child theme out of twentyeleven, and so far so good as far as the css goes, but now I want to display a featured image and I don't know how.

I added this to my functions.php;

```
// add featured images 
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(500, 200);
```

Which means featured images are enabled but it still won't show up. I have used featured images in other, premade, layouts so I know I'm not doing anything wrong as far as setting the image goes. I think I have to add a bit of code in my single.php file or maybe my post.php file? I found this piece of code;

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

and put in my (empty) single.php file of my child theme but it didn't work. What piece of code do I need and where do I need to put it to show these featured images?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'class_here')); ?>
```

or if you want to link to another size:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
    echo '<a href="' . $large_image_url[0] . '" title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" class="classes_here" >';
    the_post_thumbnail('large');
    echo '</a>';
}
?>
```

[More in codex WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Hope this helps

/Paul

Comment: I added your first code to content.php, replaced class_here with post-thumbnails, but it's still not showing up.

Comment: You do have the child theme activated in appearance and uploaded an featured image?

And what is content.php, due it ain't a wp template file.

Comment: Also... twentyeleven has theme support for post_thumbnails, so you don't have to put add_theme_support.... in your function.php file.

Out of my head twentyeleven's single.php doesn't has a post thumbnail, but when you take twentyeleven's content-single.php and put the thumbnail code there, somewhere in the loop.

content-single.php is included in single.php with get_template_part....

Comment: Thankyou Paul, I'll look into the tips you gave me. Have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Unfortunately not.. Tomorrow I can export everything to my server so I can show you the actual code and problem.